# Why Python list is getting modified in the below code

Tags: python

I am passing three lists and currently using two lists to form a addition list . But while doing so , the lists used for addition (A and P in this case) are getting modified . Why is it happening ?

```
def solve(A, P, Q):
# Your Code Here
    add=[A[i]+P[i] for i in range(len(list(A)))]
    return add

T = int(input())
for _ in range(T):
    n = int(input())
    A = map(int, input().split())
    P = map(int, input().split())
    Q = map(int, input().split())
    print(list(A))                # getting value in list 
    out_ = solve(A, P, Q)
    print(list(A))                # not getting value in list 
    print(list(Q))                
    print (out_)
```

Why am i getting value in list A before solve function but not after although I have not modified list A . Also , I am not getting anything in out_ also .

Output :

```
1
3
3 4 5
1 1 1
1 2 3
[3, 4, 5]
[]
[1, 2, 3]
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, `map()` does not return a list, but a "map object", which is an *iterator*.

Whenever you call `list()` on the result of `map()`, the first time the whole iterator is used up. The second time, it's empty.

```
>>> A = map(int, "123")
>>> list(A)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(A)
[]
```

If you never use `list()` except right after the call to `map()`, your code should work.

```
A = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

But that is basically a list comprehension:

```
A = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
```